# Why those two sed commands get different result?

Tags: regex, csv, sed

A csv file example.csv, it has

```
hello,world,wow
this,is,amazing
```

I want to get the first column elements, at the beginning I wrote a sed command like:

```
sed -n 's/\([^,]*\),*/\1/p' example.csv
```

output:

```
helloworld,now
thisis,amazing
```

Then I modified my command to the following and get what I want:

```
sed -n 's/\([^,]*\).*/\1/p' example.csv
```

output:

```
hello
this
```

command1 I used comma(,) and command2 I replaced comma with dot(.), and it works as expected, can anyone explain how sed really works to get the 1st output? What's the story behind? Is it because of the dot(.) or because of the substitution group & back-reference?

Comment: Can I suggest `cut -d, -f1 example.csv`. I'm a huge `sed` fan, but this is much easier to do with `cut`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both regexes, `([^,]*)` will consume the same part of the string - all the symbols preceding the first encountered comma. Apparently the difference is how are the remaining parts of those regexes treated.

In the first one, it's `,*` - zero or more *comma* symbols. Obviously all it might consume is 
the comma itself - the rest of the line isn't covered by a pattern.

In the second one, it's `.*` - zero or more of *any* symbols. It's not a big surprise that'll cover the remaining string completely - as it has nothing to stop at; any is, well, any. )

In both cases the pattern-covered part of the string is replaced by the contents of the capturing group (and that's, as I said already, 'all the symbols before the first comma') - and what's covered by the remaining part of the regex is just removed. So in first case the very first comma is erased, in the second - the comma and the rest of the string.

Comment: this answer is making perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind that is that the pattern matches only to the first part of the word, i.e. only the Hello, part is replaced. The part ,* takes arbitrary amount of commas, and then nothing is set to be next, i.e. nothing else matches the pattern. For example:

```
hello,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,world
```

would be replaced to

```
helloworld
```

A good example would be

```
sed -n 's/\([^,]*\),*$/\1/p' example.csv
```

This will work if and only if all the commas are at the end of the line and will trim them, e.g.

```
hello,,,,,,
```

Hope this makes the problem a bit clearer.

Comment: You may misunderstood my point.  The second command in the question is correct, I dont want to escape the dot(.), there's no dot in the csv file. do you know why the substitution grouping matches "helloworld,wow"  rather than "hello" if use the 1st command?

Answer (score 0):

On regex the . (dot) is a place holder for one, single character.

Comment: Meaning you need to escape it with a backslash `\.` unless it is in a character class `[.]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you like first word, why not use `awk`

```
awk -F, '{print $1}' file
hello
this
```

---

Using `sed` with back reference

```
sed -nr 's/([^,]*),.*/\1/p' file
hello
this
```

It seems that to make it work you need the `.*` so it get the whole line.
The `r` option make you not need to escape the parentheses `\(`

Comment: thanks,this works perfectly. I hope anyone can explain substitution grouping, back-reference for me why get the 1st output.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest *not* using `sed`?

```
cut -d, -f1 example.csv
```

Personally, I'm a huge `sed` fan, but `cut` is much more appropriate in this instance.